# Discord slash command interactions failing despite event handler logging the interactions correctly

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Following along with discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot

I've made an event handler that's working correctly and returning the expected terminal logs.

However, none of the commands that were previously working are working. I've had this happen before and I had to restart the bot and the commands started functioning correctly again.

The bit I can't figure out is the interaction are being logged in my terminal successful yet they're showing up as failed interactions in the discord.

My command handler;

```
const fs = require('fs');
const { REST } = require('@discordjs/rest');
const { Routes } = require('discord-api-types/v9');
const { clientId, guildId, token } = require('./config.json');

const commands = [];
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    commands.push(command.data.toJSON());
}

const rest = new REST({ version: '9' }).setToken(token);

(async () => {
    try {
        await rest.put(
            Routes.applicationGuildCommands(clientId, guildId),
            { body: commands },
        );

        console.log('Successfully registered application commands.');
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
})();
```

my event handler;

```
const fs = require('fs');
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const { token } = require('./config.json');

const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS] });

const eventFiles = fs.readdirSync('./events').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of eventFiles) {
    const event = require(`./events/${file}`);
    if (event.once) {
        client.once(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args));
    } else {
        client.on(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args));
    }
}

client.login(token);
```

Ping command:

```js
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders'); module.exports = { 
  data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('ping')
    .setDescription('Replies with Pong!'),
  async execute(interaction) {
    await interaction.reply('Pong!');
  },
};
```

interactionCreate event listener:

```
module.exports = { name: 'interactionCreate', execute(interaction) { console.log(${interaction.user.tag} in #${interaction.channel.name} triggered an interaction.); }, }; This is triggering correctly at least, I'm getting an output in my log that's expected.
```

And my interactionCreate although this lives in with my command handling folder/code. I'll post the folder structure below as well.

```
client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
    if (!interaction.isCommand()) return;

    const command = client.commands.get(interaction.commandName);

    //If the command doesn't exist, it will return undefined, so exit early with return. 
    if (!command) return;

    //If it does exist, call the command's .execute() method, and pass in the interaction variable as its argument.
    try {
        await command.execute(interaction);
    //In case something goes wrong, log the error and report back to the member to let them know.
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        await interaction.reply({ content: 'There was an error while executing this command!', ephemeral: true });
    }
});
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you post your ping command script?

Comment: const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');

module.exports = {
 data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
  .setName('ping')
  .setDescription('Replies with Pong!'),
 async execute(interaction) {
  await interaction.reply('Pong!');
 },
};

Comment: @theusaf can post above if that's easier!

Comment: How are you calling the ping command's `execute` function? Can you post your `interactionCreate` event listener file (if you have one), or mention if you are not listening to that event.

Comment: @theusaf updated with requested information,

Comment: I'm stumped. If you put a `console.log()` inside your `client.on("interactionCreate")`, does that run, or is nothing logged?

Comment: Logs correctly with console.log() inside client.on but the interaction still fails. These don't need to all be in the same folder using the same index.js do they? because I've split them into one. One for event handling and one for command handling

Comment: The folders shouldn't affect it. It may be that you aren't setting the commands using `client.commands.set()` in your command handler? https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/command-handling.html#reading-command-files

Comment: @theusaf I'm outputting into the terminal a `commands successfully registered`  message. I assume commands are registering correctly.

Comment: Yes, you are registering the commands' **metadata** on Discord's server, but the actual command functions are not being saved in an accessible location in your code. You also need to create a collection somewhere (`this.client.commands = new Collection`), `set` your commands,  (`this.client.commands.set(name, command)`), then get those commands later?